# Get data from request npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm-request

I'm building an app using express js and using request(v-2.88.2) to get data from an api

```
request(url, function(error, request, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

I want to use var data in other functions.

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: There are various ways. You could for example store it globally, though I would prefer passing it to the functions which need the data

Comment: @zirmax I want to use it another request so i can't simply just pass it in a function.

Comment: It really depends, but you should make it accessible in the parent scope. Use a piece of state in your frontend framework. Create a variable in the parent scope. Use redux and dispatch an appropriate action. Store it in localStorage and read it elsewhere. Use a cookie. Just make it accessible in another scope.

Comment: Also this package is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can do this by making you variable as global. its not really good method but we can do this

```
var data; 
request(url, function(error, request, body) {
data = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

by this, you can even access your data variable outside of your function too. hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `data` in other functions just pass as arguments in that functions i.e.

```
request(url, function(error, request, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    // call another function and pass as arguments
    antoherFunctions(data);

});


function anotherFunctions(data){
  // use data as per requirement 
  request(data.url, function(error, request, body) {
    var anotherData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(anotherData)
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to use it another request so i can't simply just pass it in a function.

Comment: @Deepaksingh so-called that another request in another function

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it would be hard to do much if you couldn't.

```
function doStuffWithData(theData) {
  // This is your other function

  // E.g. make another dependent request
  const secondRequestUrl = theData.url;
  request(secondRequestUrl, function(error, request, body) {
    var evenMoreData = JSON.parse(body);
    // Do even more stuff with your second request's results
  });
}

request(url, function(error, request, body) {
  var data = JSON.parse(body);

  // Use data in another function:
  doStuffWithData(data);
});
```

Comment: I want to use it another request so i can't simply just pass it in a function.

Comment: You can make your other request either in that location or inside your function that you are passing it to as an argument. Nothing stops that.